# Qual a melhor maneira de atualizar o token utilizando o refresh_token no angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Estou desenvolvendo um App (ionic v1) que, ao se comunicar com o servidor (implementado com OAuth), retorna um **token** e um **refresh_token**.

Qual seria a melhor maneira de interceptar uma requisição, entender que ela retornou um erro 401 (token inválido), enviar um refresh_token para obter um novo token e enviar novamente a mesma requisição?

Desde já, agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o meu problema, a melhor forma que encontrei foi criar um "Interceptor". Abaixo, segue o código elaborado. Espero que ajude alguém.

```
.factory('settingsService', [function() {

    var settingsServiceFactory = {};

    var _getSettings = function(requestData) {
        return {
            url: requestData.url,
            dataType: requestData.dataType || "json",
            data: requestData.data || {},
            headers: requestData.headers || {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            async: requestData.async || false,
            cache: requestData.cache || false,
            success: requestData.success || {},
            error: requestData.error || {},
            complete: requestData.complete || {},
            fail: requestData.fail || {}
        };
    };

    settingsServiceFactory.getSettings = _getSettings;

    return settingsServiceFactory;
}])

.factory('authInterceptorService', ['$log', '$q', '$location', '$localStorage', '$injector', 'settingsService',
    function($log, $q, $location, $localStorage, $injector, settingsService) {

        var inFlightAuthRequest = null;
        var authInterceptorServiceFactory = {};

        var _request = function(config) {

            config.headers = config.headers || {};

            var authData = $localStorage.authorizationData;

            if (authData) {
                $log.log('[_request -> access_token]: ', authData.access_token);
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + authData.access_token;
            }

            return config;
        };

        var _responseError = function(response) {

            $log.warn('[_responseError -> response]: ', response);

            switch (response.status) {
                case 401:

                    if (!$localStorage.authorizationData) {
                        $location.path('/login');
                        return;
                    }

                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    if (!inFlightAuthRequest) {

                        var requestData = {
                            url: $localStorage.serviceBase + '/token',
                            data: {
                                refresh_token: $localStorage.authorizationData.refresh_token,
                                grant_type: "refresh_token"
                            }
                        };

                        var settings = settingsService.getSettings(requestData);
                        settings.method = "POST";

                        inflightAuthRequest = $injector.get("$http")(settings);
                    }

                    inflightAuthRequest.then(function(r) {
                        inflightAuthRequest = null;
                        if (r.data && r.data.access_token && r.data.refresh_token) {

                            $localStorage.authorizationData = r.data;
                            $log.warn('[new token]: ', $localStorage.authorizationData.access_token);

                            $injector.get("$http")(response.config).then(function(resp) {
                                deferred.resolve(resp);
                            }, function(resp) {
                                deferred.reject();
                            });
                        } else {
                            deferred.reject();
                        }
                    }, function(response) {
                        inflightAuthRequest = null;
                        deferred.reject();
                        delete $localStorage.authorizationData;
                        $location.path('/login');
                        return;
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        };

        authInterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
        authInterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;

        return authInterceptorServiceFactory;
    }
]);
```